# Property name for $f(p + \Delta) = f(p) + \Delta$

Tags: functions

What is the name for the following property (if that matters, $p$ and $\Delta$ are nonnegative rational numbers, while $f$ maps to nonnegative rational numbers)?
$$f(p + \Delta) = f(p) + \Delta$$

**Edit 1 (context)**
The particular case that I am dealing with defines $f$ as follows with $Q$ being a positive rational number and requires $\Delta$ to be divisible by $Q$:
$$f(p) = Q \left\lceil\frac{p}{Q}\right\rceil$$

**Edit 2 (the property holds)**
\begin{align*}
f(p + \Delta) &= f(p) + \Delta \\
Q \left\lceil\frac{p + \Delta}{Q}\right\rceil &= Q \left\lceil\frac{p}{Q}\right\rceil + \Delta \\
Q \left(\left\lceil\frac{p}{Q}\right\rceil + \frac{\Delta}{Q}\right) &= Q \left\lceil\frac{p}{Q}\right\rceil + \Delta\;\ldots\;\text{$\Delta$ is divisible by $Q$} \\
Q \left\lceil\frac{p}{Q}\right\rceil + \Delta &= Q \left\lceil\frac{p}{Q}\right\rceil + \Delta
\end{align*}

Comment: affine function? we have f(x) = f(0+x)=f(0)+x for every $x$

Comment: The function is not constant, and the effect is achievable using ceil or floor operator.

Comment: @samjoe what exactly?

Comment: @samjoe well I learned about affine function at school (when I was ~12 yo).

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo I doubt floor function will work, we have 3 = floor(2.9+0.2) ≠ 2.2 = floor(2.9)+0.2

Comment: What are the quatifiers here? You want this to hold for *all* $p$ and $\Delta$ or for some. Or you say that *there exist some* values for $p$ and $\Delta$ so that $f(p+\Delta)=f(p)+\Delta$? Or a mixed form? I cannot see how to answer this without this information.

Comment: Please see my Edit 1 for the particular case I am dealing with.

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo You should start tagging people in your comments so we see who you answer to. If you answered me, then this does not really help.

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo On top of that, the question is now quite ill posed. Seems like you are asking for a name of a class of function include the case you mention. But it is not clear at all to me what you really want. Furthermore your example does not satisfies the property you mention.

Comment: @Surb Please see my Edit 2.  Sorry for being incomplete in the original question.

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo Your edits making your question gradually more unclear. You ask us about the name of a property. We gain *no* information from the specific function you are working with. As I said above, what we need are *quantifiers*, i.e. "for all" or "there exist" for $p$ and $\Delta$. If it is unclear to you what I am asking for, then I can explain, but it seems you are ignoring this.

Comment: @M.Winter My Edit 2 show that $p$ and $\Delta$ can be any nonnegative rational number, while $Q$ can be any positive rational number.  I am asking if $f(p + \Delta) = f(p) + \Delta$ has got any name like distributivity of $f$ over $p + \Delta$.  Please kindly tell me what missing information you would like to know.

Comment: Again adding on M.Winter (who you should thank for being so patient and nice to help you formatting the question): Note that
it is not true that for every $a,b>0$ it holds $\lceil a+b \rceil \neq \lceil a \rceil +\lceil b \rceil $ (in your second step of edit 2). Take $a=b=1/3$.

Comment: @samjoe you're welcome. Affine functions are pretty well explained on wikipedia

Comment: @M.Winter Thank you for being so patient and nice in helping me with my question.

Comment: @Surb But in my case, $b$ is always an integer because $\Delta$ is required to be divisible by $Q$.

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo Thank you for providing the information, and sorry if I sounded rude! I do not know if this property has any specific name, but I do not think so.

Comment: @M.Winter You are welcome, and sorry for not being crystal clear since the beginning because I thought a name for $f(p + \Delta) = f(p) + \Delta$ should not have needed any proof of that the equality itself holds.

Comment: @M.Winter Okay if that has no name.  I am hoping that exposing this to many people over the Internet should increase the chance for someone to recognize $f(p+\Delta) = f(p) + \Delta$ if the person has ever encountered it before in the person's life.

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo What do you need the name for? You just want a short name for it to refer to, or you want to look it up online? If the name is not so well known that until now noone recognized it, you have mostly free hand to name it whatever you want.

Comment: @M.Winter I need the name for both, namely referring to the key property in my work and looking it up online to find similar works using this key property.

Comment: @TadeusPrastowo Note that you are not obligated to accept an answer if it does not fit your question in the final form. Most of the time it is okay to wait several days for an appropriate answer. If you are okay with supinf's answer then I see no problem, but otherwise you will definitely discourage other users to answer because you already accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property implies
$$
 f(y)=f(0)+y
$$

for all nonnegative rational $y$.

So this means that $f$ will always be an affine function.
However, note that most affine functions don't satisfy your property (and can have a slope different from $1$).

Comment: Please see my Edit 1.  Sorry for the lack of information in the original question.

Comment: And, kindly see my Edit 2.  Once again, sorry for the lack of information in the original question.

Comment: I think this is the closest.